# C++ Inject into Java application

Tags: java, c++, dll-injection

I'm having a really hard time figuring out why I cannot get my hooks to work in a java application..

I create a C++ WINAPI window. I load my "hook" dll and every time I send fake input to the application, it raises a flag perfectly fine.

However, if I do the same with a Java application, it does NOT work at all!

My dll looks like this:

```
#include <windows.h>

HINSTANCE hInstance = nullptr;
HHOOK MouseHook = {0};   /** Structure for hooking the mouse **/
HHOOK KeyboardHook = {0};  /** Structure for hooking the keyboard **/

LRESULT __stdcall MouseHookProc(int Code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (Code == HC_ACTION)
    {
        MSLLHOOKSTRUCT* Info = reinterpret_cast<MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam);
        if ((Info->flags & LLMHF_INJECTED) == LLMHF_INJECTED)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "DETECTED Mouse", "", 0);
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(MouseHook, Code, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT __stdcall KeyboardHookProc(int Code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (Code == HC_ACTION)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* Info = reinterpret_cast<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam);
        if ((Info->flags & LLKHF_INJECTED) == LLKHF_INJECTED)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "DETECTED Keyboard", "", 0);
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(KeyboardHook, Code, wParam, lParam);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool __stdcall DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            hInstance = hinstDLL;
            SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardHookProc, hInstance, 0);
            SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookProc, hInstance, 0);
        }
        break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(KeyboardHook);
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(MouseHook);
        }
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then I created a C++ WINAPI application with the following `WM_CREATE` block:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    LoadLibrary("JavaHook.dll");
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 100, 100, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,100, 100,0,0);
break;
```

The MessageBox of the MouseHook pops up. This is expected behaviour.

However with Java I did:

```
public class HookTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Window");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        System.loadLibrary("JavaHook");
    } 
}
```

Then I used SendInput on the application like so:

```
INPUT input;
input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
input.mi.mouseData = 0;
input.mi.dx =  100 * (65536 / GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)); //x being coord in pixels
input.mi.dy =  100 * (65536 / GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)); //y being coord in pixels
input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
```

and NOTHING pops up. I tried using `mouse_event` and `keybd_event`, still nothing. I tried using a Java mouse listener and keyboard listener and faking events.. Still NOTHING..

The hook loads for sure because I can see my mouse lag for a good 3 seconds before I can move it. Also made a popup to confirm it upon load.

However, I still cannot figure out why it doesn't work on the Java application. Any ideas how I can get them to work. Or is there another way to do it for Java preferably from C/C++? If not, is there a way to do it in Java?

Comment: The usual way to communicate between Java and the underlying OS is  through JNI, not through writing hook DLL's and assuming Java works the same way as C++.

Comment: Yes but the way to communicate with an application through JNI is to have access to the application's source. I' trying to "hook" a Java app's mouse events.

Comment: Well, you make no mention of the JVM.  Isn't that what you should focus on?  If the JVM doesn't want to play your game, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read remarks to [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation.

Specifically it says that the thread that installed a global hook should continue to process Windows messages in order to allow both 32-bit and 64-bit applications to run the hook code in the context of the hooking application.

So, I suggest you create a separate thread from DllMain. The thread will install a hook and then run into GetMessage/ProcessMessage loop: http://pastebin.com/JmMvMX78

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
HHOOK MouseHook = {0};
HHOOK KeyboardHook = {0};
 
LRESULT WINAPI MouseHookProc(int Code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (Code == HC_ACTION) {
        printf("Mouse\n");
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(MouseHook, Code, wParam, lParam);
}
 
LRESULT WINAPI KeyboardHookProc(int Code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (Code == HC_ACTION) {
        printf("Keyboard\n");
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(KeyboardHook, Code, wParam, lParam);
}
 
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID param) {
    HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)param;
    MouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookProc, hInstance, 0);
    KeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardHookProc, hInstance, 0);
 
    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message, (HWND)-1, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }
 
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(KeyboardHook);
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(MouseHook);
 
    return 0;
}
 
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) {
    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        CloseHandle(CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, hinstDLL, 0, NULL));
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked. I can't believe I missed such a small detail. I actually created a `std::thread` that for some reason didn't work but yours worked.. I realized that you put the hooks within the thread. Doing this fixed it.